# SQL Server Sum of two columns in where clause with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as below and need to join the two table and need to get the result table.

Could anyone help me please?

```
New_Table               
Emp CodeEmp Name    BF  OOF TB
11111   AAAA        Y   Off 1
22222   BBBB        Y   Off 0.75
22222   BBBB        Y   Off 0.25
33333   CCCC        Y   On  0.98
44444   DDDD        Y   Off 1
55555   EEEE        Y   Off 1

Old_Table               
Emp Code    Emp Name       BF   OOF TB
11111       AAAA           Y    Off 1
22222       BBBB           Y    Off 0.25
22222       BBBB           Y    Off 0.75
33333       CCCC           Y    Off 0.98



Result              
Emp Code    Emp Name    BF  OOF TB
44444       DDDD        Y   Off 1
55555       EEEE        Y   Off 1
```

I have tried the below SQL query buy i am getting the Emp Code 222222 which i dont need because the sum of TB for Emp Code 222222 is equal ie 1 = 1.

```
INSERT INTO Result ([Emp Code]
      ,[Emp Name]
      ,[BF]
      ,[OOF]
      ,[TB])
SELECT a.[Emp Code]
      ,a.[Emp Name]
      ,a.[BF]
      ,a.[OOF]
      ,a.[TB]
 FROM New_Table a left join Old_Table b 
 on a.[Emp Code] = b.[Emp Code] where 
 a.[BF] = 'Y' and a.[OOF] = b.[OOF] and a.[TB] > b.[TB]
 and a.[TB] > 0.5 ;
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the records in New_Table but not in Old_Table?

Comment: Good point from @Dave.Gugg. You said you want to join the tables but are getting values from one of them only.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM, GROUP BY and HAVING clause.

```
INSERT INTO Result ([Emp Code]
      ,[Emp Name]
      ,[BF]
      ,[OOF]
      ,[TB])
SELECT a.[Emp Code]
      ,a.[Emp Name]
      ,a.[BF]
      ,a.[OOF]
      ,sum(a.[TB])
 FROM New_Table a left join Old_Table b 
 on a.[Emp Code] = b.[Emp Code] where 
 a.[BF] = 'Y' and a.[OOF] = b.[OOF]
 and a.[TB] > 0.5 
 group by 
    a.[Emp Code]
      ,a.[Emp Name]
      ,a.[BF]
      ,a.[OOF]
 having sum(a.[TB]) > sum(b.[TB])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AND (a.TB + COALESCE(B.TB, 0)) != 1
```

this will eliminate 22222 for you.

Alternatively, you could try a subquery.

```
and a.[Emp Code] not in (select [Emp Code] from New_Table group by [Emp Code] 
having sum(TB) = 1)
```

You can add any where clause restrictions to the subquery you need.

Answer (score 0):

USE `EXCEPT` operator to find new records.
I modified your query only. Can you try the code below:

```
INSERT INTO Result ([Emp Code]
          ,[Emp Name]
          ,[BF]
          ,[OOF]
          ,[TB])
    SELECT a.[Emp Code]
          ,a.[Emp Name]
          ,a.[BF]
          ,a.[OOF]
          ,a.[TB]
     FROM New_Table a left join Old_Table b 
     on a.[Emp Code] = b.[Emp Code] where 
     a.[BF] = 'Y' and a.[OOF] = b.[OOF] and a.[TB] > b.[TB]
    group by a.[Emp Code]
          ,a.[Emp Name]
          ,a.[BF]
          ,a.[OOF]
          ,a.[TB]
    having sum(a.tb)>1
```

Comment: This code doesn't actually use the `EXCEPT` operator?!? What solution are you trying to suggest?